# Undefined argument when declaring function in Octave

Tags: function, octave

I get undefined variable/argument when trying to define my own random generator function.

Code:

```
function result = myrand(n, t, p, d)
    a = 200 * t + p
    big_rand = a * n
    result = big_rand / 10**d
    return;
endfunction

mrand = myrand(5379, 0, 91, 4)
```

error:

```
>> myrand
error: 't' undefined near line 2 column 15
error: called from
myrand at line 2 column 7
```

Comment: Your code works for me in Octave. Do you execute it on the commandline? if it's part of a script (for example foo.m) make sure the first line doesn't start with the function declaration. A common way is to add `1;` at the beginning

Comment: Besides the error, this is not really `random`, not even `pseudo-random`, as your "random" number is simply `(200*t*n+p*n)/(10*d)`, which is a simple one-to-one function of four variables.

Comment: Did you save this as `myrand.m` and *then* called `mrand = myrand(5379, 0, 91, 4)`, or did you execute both function declaration and function call in the commandline? (MATLAB'd throw you an error "function declarations not allowed in this environment" in that case, not sure about Octave)

Comment: @Adriaan yes, octave allows in-line function definitions, matlab doesn't. (although apparently it sounds like 2016b will)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't start a script with a *function* keyword.
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Script-Files.html

This works:

```
disp("Running...")
function result = myrand(n, t, p, d)
     a = 200 * t + p
     big_rand = a * n
     result = big_rand / 10**d
     return;
endfunction

mrand = myrand(5379, 0, 91, 4)
```

You should get:

```
warning: function 'myrand' defined within script file 'myrand.m'   
Running ...  
a =  91  
big_rand =  489489  
result =  48.949  
mrand =  48.949
```

Comment: Thanks, but you have any idea on why it works like this !??