# Undefined variable in execution of octave code

Tags: octave

When the following simple code is executed:

```
function u=complexu(z)
  u = zeros(size(z));
  u = z+exp(-1*z)+z*z;
end
```

The output is as follows:

```
tester

error: 'z' undefined near line 2 column 18
error: called from
    tester at line 2 column 5
```

The name of the file that contains the function is `tester.m`. I have ensured that the current directory contains all the files of interest. I still can't figure out why this problem is occurring. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Either add something before your Funktion, '1;' is usual or make a proper script file (same function Name and file Name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined argument when declaring function in Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915098/undefined-argument-when-declaring-function-in-octave)

Comment: I have renamed the function name to be the same as the file name and added `1;` before the function name. Still the following error is returned:

error: 'z' undefined near line 3 column 18
error: called from
    tester at line 3 column 5

Comment: How do you call the function? Please include all, not only one part of your code

Comment: You have to pass the value of `z` to the function. If you have renamed the file to the same name as the function, do **not** add the `1;` at the beginning; that forces your file to become a script, and that's not what you want in this case.