# Accessing argument inside function

Tags: octave

While trying to access function argument in octave i am getting following error : **error: 's' undefined near line 5 column 18.**
Below is the attached code snippet

```
function index = find_template_1D(t, s)
    % TODO: Locate template t in signal s and return index
    for i = size(s)
        if (s(i)==t(1) && s(i+1) == t(2) && s(i+2)==t(3))
            index = i;
        endif
    endfor
endfunction

index = find_template_1D(t, s);
```

Can someone help me to figure out what is the exact issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined argument when declaring function in Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915098/undefined-argument-when-declaring-function-in-octave)

Comment: One thought, size returns an array. If s is a 2x3 matrix, size(s) = [2 3].   Is that what you want your for loop to iterate through? It will evaluate for i = 2 and i =3 and that’s it.  Maybe you want     for i = 1:numel(s)   ?

Comment: Regarding the error, one can only assume you are calling the function with two arguments? And you have previously defined those arguments?

Comment: As Nick said, I'm very sure you want numel instead oft sie. Btw, there already is a funktion which does this: strfind